# Android Studio Error - "Android Emulator is incompatible with Hyper-V"

Tags: android-studio, virtualización

Al tratar de crear un emulador virtual en Android Studio me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Android Emulator is incompatible with Hyper-V

**¿A que se puede deber?**

Comment: Deactiva el Hyper-V :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Microsoft Hyper-V es un programa de virtualización basado en un hipervisor para los sistemas de 64-bits​** con los procesadores basados en AMD-V o Tecnología de virtualización Intel. Lo mas probable y lo que tengo entendido es que **Hyper-V es incompatible con el emulador de Android Studio** por una coincidencia en que **ambos usan HAXM para correr**.

Para solucionar este problema te recomiendo que **instales otro emulador como Genymotion** y que pruebes o que descargues el **emulador oficial de android para Windows** desde [aqui](https://www.visualstudio.com/es/vs/msft-android-emulator/).

Si sigue sin funcionar date una vuelta por las p**reguntes similares que se hicieron en la comunidad en ingles:**

- [Can I run Android Studio (Android SDK emulator) in a Microsoft
  hyper-v virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293574/can-i-run-android-studio-android-sdk-emulator-in-a-microsoft-hyper-v-virtual-m)
- [How to Disable Hyper-V and install HAXM in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301234/how-to-disable-hyper-v-and-install-haxm-in-windows-8)

**Espero que te sirva!**